# Reproducable cryptographic hashes of Rust structs/enums

Tags: rust, endianness, sha256

Currently I'm using the following code to get sha256 hashes of Rust structs and enums.

```
pub fn sha256<T: Sized + Serialize>(ser: T) -> [u8; 32] {
    let str = ron::ser::to_string(&ser).expect("serialization has failed");

    let mut hasher = Sha256::new();
    hasher.update(str);
    let hash = hasher.finalize();
    *hash.as_ref()
}
```

This works, but is far from ideal:

- If RON serialisation changes, the hashes will change.
- Serialisation is wasting CPU cycles.

There is a `.hash()` method on many types, but that seems to be for 64-bit non-crypto hashing (HashMap, etc.).

How can I cryptographically-hash arbitrary Rust structs and enums, such that the hashes will be identical regardless of architecture/word-size/endianess?  (I do not use `usize` in these.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hash an object with a cryptographic hash, you must necessarily turn it into a stream of bytes, since that's the only thing that cryptographic hashes accept.  We would generally call this serialization.

There are some things you can do:

- Find the fastest general-purpose serialization format you can.  JSON is not good for this, since it doesn't serialize byte sequences efficiently, so you could try CBOR, Msgpack, or some other binary format.
- Add tests to your code that common structures hash to expected values so that you can verify that they work as expected and avoid breaking things unexpectedly.
- Add a version field to your hash, if possible, so you can bump the version if you need to change the serializer or the byte structure of the serialization.
- Use a faster hash than SHA-256, such as SHA-512, SHA-512/256, or BLAKE2b (on 64-bit systems) or BLAKE2s (on 32-bit systems) to reduce the cost of the overall operation.

Alternatively, you could try building a custom `Hasher` implementation which can also output a SHA-256 value.  Your structure would then need to implement `Hash` instead of `Serialize` and you'd do the hashing incrementally.  This might or might not be faster.

Comment: Are the non-crypto hashes, used for HashMap, architecture dependent?  If not, how do they get their sequence of bytes, and can I get them in the same way?

Comment: Possibly.  You'd have to look and see whether the default implementation hashes in the native endianness or in a fixed one.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/hash/mod.rs.html#570-578 shows that the built-in hashes (e.g. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hash.html#impl-Hash-11 i32) take no account of endianness.  If I think its worthwhile, I can copy, modify and paste the implementations of the Hash trait into a new EndianHash trait.